# About the flow chart in programming languages

Tags: flowchart

The target of the flowchart to get the sum of integer numbers from 1 to 3

The variables I have:

- N stands for the initial value
- sum

so my question is why is variable N considerd a counter and why sum is considerd an accumulating variable

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I reformatted the question to try to make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `N` is used as a control variable in a loop. (it goes from 1 to 2 to 3 - as a counter) and sum is updated on every iteration of the loop (it *accumulates* 1, 2 and 3 to form the result).